# How to get project creation date using SonarQube Web API

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

In Sonarqube 6.7.3, is it possible to get the project creation date using Web API?
In the earlier version, using "**api/resources**", would return the value "**creationDate**".

Comment: May you should investigate the usage of  api/projects/index and set the versions property